# How can I independently resize Pictures pasted to a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, image, resize, worksheet

I am looking for a way to resize pictures of tables revised and pasted daily to a report.  Here is a description of my objective, problem, and suggested resolution (that I can’t figure out how to code).

**MY OBJECTIVE:** my code needs to - 1) copy a Picture of a table called TABLE A from the TABLE Worksheet and then - 2) paste the TABLE A Picture to Cell B2 on the OUTPUT Sheet, then - 3) resize the pasted TABLE A Picture.  LATER, when - 1) the OUTPUT Sheet is next activated, to - 2) delete all Pictures on the OUTPUT Sheet including the existing TABLE A Picture pasted in Cell B2 (this code has been omitted for brevity), and - 3) copy a new and updated TABLE A from the TABLE Sheet,  then - 4) paste the newly copied Picture of TABLE A to B2 on the OUTPUT Sheet, then - 5) resize the newly pasted TABLE A to the exact dimensions as applied to the previously pasted but now deleted TABLE A.  ***THE PROBLEM: VBA assigns a Picture Name as a ShapeRange (say “Picture 1” or “ShapeRange (1)) to the original TABLE A Picture pasted to the OUTPUT Sheet, then after “Picture 1” has been deleted, VBA assigns a different Name  or ShapeRange (say “Picture 2” or “ShapeRange (2)) to the new copy of each and every updated TABLE A copied from the TABLE Sheet and pasted to the same location on the OUTPUT Sheet.  Unfortunately, my VBA Picture (or ShapeRange) resizing code has no way to recognize that the Picture Name has changed, so it will try, as in this example, to resize “Picture 1” (which no longer exists) instead of the newly pasted “Picture 2”.***   **RESOLUTION:** I either need code that makes the Name of each new Picture copy/pasted to a specific location on the OUTPUT Sheet always be the same Name as the Picture previously deleted from the same location (e.g. every new TABLE A pasted to the OUTPUT Sheet is always Named “Picture 1”), OR the resizing code is changed so it recognizes and is applicable to whatever new Name VBA assigns to each newly copied TABLE A Picture that is pasted to the OUTPUT Sheet replacing the previously deleted Picture’s Name.

A solution to this problem will be much appreciated?

````
'Copies TABLE Picture and Pastes on OUTPUT Worksheet
Worksheets("TABLE").Range("a1:O29").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Worksheets("OUTPUT").Paste _
Destination:=Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("B2")

'Resizes TABLE Picture on OUTPUT Worksheet
        Dim Shp As Shape
        Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long

            Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

            lHeight = Shp.Height
            lWidth = Shp.Width

            hp.Height = 3 * 72 * lHeight / lWidth
            Shp.Width = 4.75 * 72

'Copies CHART Picture and Pastes on OUTPUT Worksheet
Worksheets("CHART").Range("A1:j17").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Worksheets("OUTPUT").Paste _
Destination:=Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("B18")


End Sub```
````

Comment: Per [ShapeRange object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) documenation, `ShapeRange` *Represents a shape range, which is a set of shapes on a document*. Your code specifically refers to the first shape in the set.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense what you are trying to do now. As the delete part of your code is omitted, does it delete *all* pictures from the "Output" sheet? And once an image is deleted from the sheet the `Shapes.Count` decrements for each picture removed, which basically means if *all* pictures are removed, it will start from `Shapes(1)` again. So how many pictures in total are you trying to resize?

Comment: Works perfectly Samuel.  You are a lifesaver.  I can't thank you enough. Where can I submit an "attaboy" for your perseverance and expertise?  It is well deserved!

Comment: Just mark the answer as accepted which shows the community 'this fixed my problem' - as for an 'attaboy' that gives me rep points (so does an upvote) so both of those things would really be the only way but it's not expected, only do it if the answer is worthy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it makes a lot more sense with your edit.

You mentioned you want to trigger it on `Worksheet_Activate` so the below is written for this event.

It is more or less what you had written, but uses `Shapes.Count` as the index number for the `Shapes()` collection. This means the most recent shape added will be the one affected by our changes.

I added a statement to rename it (the name of the source sheet) but that can be excluded if there is no need for it.

I've also contained the brunt of the code within a `With` statement to shorten our code as a lot of the calls require the sheet qualification.

I tested this with the following differences:

- `Worksheets("DATA")` was tested as `Worksheets("Sheet1")`
- `Worksheets("OUTPUT")` was tested as `Worksheets("Sheet2")`
- `Worksheets("CHART")` was tested as `Worksheets("Sheet3")`

I manually deleted both pictures from `Sheet2` each time and then navigated away from and then back to `Sheet2` to trigger the code again - Each time I got the same results as expected (screenshots below code).

### My Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name = "OUTPUT" Then

    'Copies TABLE Picture and Pastes on OUTPUT Worksheet
    Worksheets("DATA").Range("a1:O29").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Worksheets("OUTPUT").Paste Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("B2")

    With Worksheets("OUTPUT").Shapes(Worksheets("OUTPUT").Shapes.Count)
        .Name = "DATA"

    'Resizes TABLE Picture on OUTPUT Worksheet
        Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long

        lHeight = .Height
        lWidth = .Width

        .Height = 3 * 72 * lHeight / lWidth
        .Width = 4.75 * 72
    End With

    'Copies CHART Picture and Pastes on OUTPUT Worksheet
    Worksheets("CHART").Range("A1:j17").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Worksheets("OUTPUT").Paste Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("B18")
End If
End Sub
```

### Screenshot of output:

The data in the "DATA" and "CHART" ranges that are copied are filled with "Sheet1" and "Sheet3" respectively as filler data.

After numerous tests and manually deleting the pasted pictures each time before navigating away from and back to "Sheet2" ("OUTPUT") this is the constant result:

[image: Screenshot of expected output on Sheet2]

Comment: Thanks for your response Samuel.  Perhaps I misunderstood your solution, but I’m still stuck.  However, after trying several other approaches, none of which worked, I’ve developed a more precise description of the exact problem which needs resolution.  Unfortunately, I don’t know how to post it here given the text length limitation.  Any suggestion on how to post my refined request?  Your continuing help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @Foustcr thanks for the ping. I've read your updated question but to me you are asking the same thing in different words. I think to make it clearer, explain what you mean by `independently resize multiple images`. Maybe even add some before and after screenshots to show what it should look like. My solution gives guidance on how to loop through all the shapes and resize each one, one by one, if they are the right type or name. I'll update it to make it a bit clearer when I'm on my pc next.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Samuel.  I'd love to provide my explanation but as far as I can tell, comments here are limited to 600 characters.  My post is larger than that.  Can you tell me now to post the longer text?  Or, I could just post it in several several posts to be linked together.  Please advise on how best to proceed.

Comment: Just edit your question to include the additional information.

Comment: @Foustcr I've added a working solution to my answer based on my undestanding of your question... If it doesn't resolve your issue, update your question with more info including sample data before and after and I'll have a look then.

Comment: Works perfectly Samuel. You are a lifesaver. I can't thank you enough. Where can I submit an "attaboy" for your perseverance and expertise? It is well deserved!